# retrive string value from records and insert into another column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have employee table with following structure  and data.

```
id       name       empDetails                                                 phone
1        John       phone:7845982563,pinCode:7895645,subCode:22    
2        pitt       phone:7889451524,pinCode:2565479,subCode:24
3        ken        empId:3243,phone:283241524,pinCode:2563479,subCode:25  
4        rancho     empId:3263,phone:454424154,pinCode:5565479,subCode:24  
.         .                 .   

Sometimes phone poistion will be after empId also.
```

Now I want to check if column empDetails

have string phone if yes then get phone number and insert it into new phone column in the same row.

We can check if record contains string phone in this way.

```
SELECT employee.empDetails FROM employee WHERE  employee.empDetails LIKE '%phone:%'
```

But how we can retrive phone number and insert it into another column for same record?

Thanks,
Aryan

Comment: Why don't you separate the data? Have separate columns for phone, pinCode, subCode, etc.? It would make retrieval of the information much easier. If it's the case where a lot of the parameters may not have values, you could always store the information in a vertical table and join it on the user's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT replace(SUBSTRING_INDEX(empDetails,',',1),'phone:','') as phone 
FROM Table1 
where empDetails REGEXP '[[:<:]]phone[[:>:]]';
```

Check working fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/802d2/18

Please go with the advice of  spaceman817, use separate columns.

Hope this will help.

~K

---

Suppose your phone could be at any position start,middle & end. For Example:

```
(1, 'John', 'phone:7845982563,pinCode:7895645,subCode:22'),
(2, 'pitt', 'pinCode:2565479,subCode:24,phone:7889451524'),
    (3, 'vk', 'pinCode:2565479,phone:7889451524,subCode:24');
```

Use below query:

```
SELECT  
replace(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(empDetails,LOCATE('phone:',empDetails)),',',1),'phone:','') as phone
FROM Table1 where empDetails REGEXP '[[:<:]]phone[[:>:]]';
```

---OUTPUT---

```
PHONE
7845982563
7889451524
7889451524
```

Check update [sql fiddle with working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd234/8):

Hope this will help!

Comment: But my String `phone` position is not fixed , sometimes it comes after empId. I have updated my question

Comment: Can you do it in php using explode by ',' & check for phone & grab the value.

Comment: @Ran Chekc my updated answer, added handling for different positions

Answer (score 2):

```
update  employee.empDetails set phone = cast(replace(empDetails, 'phone:', '') as unsigned) 
where employee.empDetails LIKE '%phone:%'
```

Assuming phone number will be always prefixed by 'phone:'

 not a clean answer. But will do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks for reply @Akhil but I don't want to remove any content from empDetails column .

Comment: We are just updating only phone field. Not touching/updating empDetails column

Comment: yup, you are true,But my String phone position is not fixed , sometimes it comes after empId. I have updated my question. So your answer works only if ` phone` is in first place .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
update  employee set 
phone = SUBSTR(SUBSTRING_INDEX(empDetails,'phone:',-1) from 1 for  instr(SUBSTRING_INDEX(empDetails,'phone:',-1),',')-1)
where employee.empDetails LIKE '%phone:%'
```

plz see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10c8c4/40